# Как зациклить анимацию?

Tags: javascript, css

Как зациклить анимацию в обратном направлении?

```css
.train {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 177px;
  height: 160px;
  left: 0;
  transition: left 5s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 1, 1);
}
```

```html
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    
    <body>
    
      <img class="train" src="https://js.cx/clipart/train.gif" onclick="this.style.left='450px'">
    
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

На `@keyframes` такое можно сделать? Нужно, чтобы поезд развернулся и поехал в обратном направлении. Сам разворот могу сделать, но там в итоге получается много кода.

Существует ли оптимальный вариант?

Answer (score 2):

На `@keyframes` будет как то так:

```css
@keyframes anime {
  0% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  50% {
    left: 450px;
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  55% {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    left: 450px
  }
  100% {
    left: 0px;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
}

.train {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 177px;
  height: 160px;
  left: 0;
  animation: anime 5s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 1, 1);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <img class="train" src="https://js.cx/clipart/train.gif">

</body>

</html>
```

вот хорошая [статья](https://html5book.ru/css3-animation/) про анимации